# Android SQLite data availability in multiusers-aware applications

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Consider an application is not a [singleton](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multiuser-apps) (android:singleUser=”false”) in android device and it has stored certain information in the SQLite DB under a particular user. When the user switch happens on the device, will the data being stored as part of the other user in SQLite be unavailable to the application as the current user is different now?

What is the general behaviour of SQLite DB in the multiuser-aware applications?